# How to send email with attachment using InputStream and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, email, inputstream

The situation is like this:

First, we generate a file in the memory, we can get a `InputStream` object.
Second the *InputStream* object must be send as a attachment of a email. The language is Java, we use Spring to send email.

I have found a lot of information, but I cannot find how to send an email attachment using `InputStream`. I try to do like this:

```
InputStreamSource iss= new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream("c:\\a.txt"));
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
message.addAttachment("attachment", iss);
```

But I get an  exception:

> Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument. JavaMail
>   requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every
>   call.

Comment: did you manage to do this? I've got the same problem. It doesn't quite make sense as the InputStreamResource is new and haven't been used before, not sure why Spring throws that exception?!

Comment: @Stef did you manage to do this? What I've managed til now it using a ByteArrayOutputStream and than: message.addAttachment(fileName, new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
But for some reason it works when run as dev profile on the ide and not when build & run as java -jar target/projectName.jar. I get a com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable

Comment: Sorry Edmond, I don't remember. I must have I guess, but don't even remember in what project this was :)

Comment: InputStreamResource implementation always returns true on method isOpen().
that is the problem.

Answer (score 72):

For files generated *in memory*, you may use `ByteArrayResource`. Just convert your `InputStream` object using [`IOUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from the [*Apache Commons IO*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library.

It is quite simple:

```
helper.addAttachment("attachement",
new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Comment: This can also be done without a library using the following:
helper.addAttachment(ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME, new ByteArrayResource(attachmentContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), MediaType.TEXT_HTML.toString());

Comment: since attachment is converted to byte[], is there a way that we can attach a file with size is bigger than 2GB?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at the spring reference chapter [24.3 Using the JavaMail MimeMessageHelper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mail-javamail-mime)

The example is from there, I think it do want you want to do:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
sender.setHost("mail.host.com");

MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();

// use the true flag to indicate you need a multipart message
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
helper.setTo("test@host.com");

helper.setText("Check out this image!");

// let's attach the infamous windows Sample file (this time copied to c:/)
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(new File("c:/Sample.jpg"));

helper.addAttachment("CoolImage.jpg", resource );

sender.send(message);
```

if you want to use a Stream, then you can use

```
ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));
```

instead of FileSystemResource

Comment: yeah,i know this. what i wanna know is how to send attachment with a InputStream Object rather than a file. because i  generate a file in the memory , i don't want to save it on the disk.

Answer (score 2):

You can make simple implementation of InputStreamSource and pass fresh InputStream in it, as requested:

```
InputStreamSource iss = new InputStreamSource() {
    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        // provide fresh InputStream
        return new FileInputStream("c:\\a.txt");
    }
}
MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
message.addAttachment("attachment", iss);
```

Answer (score 1):

The working examples are:

1) Attachment is an `InputStreamSource` interface

```
public void send() throws IOException, MessagingException {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = createInMemoryDocument("body");
    final InputStreamSource attachment = new ByteArrayResource(stream.toByteArray());
    final MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
    helper.setSubject("subject");
    helper.setFrom("from@from.com");
    helper.setTo("to@to.com");
    helper.setReplyTo("replyTo@replyTo.com");
    helper.setText("stub", false);
    helper.addAttachment("document.txt", attachment);
    javaMailSender.send(message);
}
```

2) Attachment is an `DataSource` interface

```
public void send() throws IOException, MessagingException {
        final ByteArrayOutputStream document = createInMemoryDocument("body");
        final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(document.toByteArray());
        final DataSource attachment = new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream, "application/octet-stream");
        final MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setSubject("subject");
        helper.setFrom("from@from.com");
        helper.setTo("to@to.com");
        helper.setReplyTo("replyTo@replyTo.com");
        helper.setText("stub", false);
        helper.addAttachment("document.txt", attachment);
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
```

**The explanation:**

> Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument.
>   JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for
>   every call.

This message could appear if the developer use an implementation of `InputStreamSource` that return `true` in the `isOpen()` method.

There is a special check in the method `MimeMessageHelper#addAttacment()`:

```
public void addAttachment(String attachmentFilename, InputStreamSource inputStreamSource, String contentType) {
    //...
    if (inputStreamSource instanceof Resource && ((Resource) inputStreamSource).isOpen()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument. " +
        "JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every call.");
    }
    //...
}
```

`InputStreamResource#isOpen()` always return `true` that makes impossible to use this implementation as an attachment:

```
public class InputStreamResource extends AbstractResource {
   //...
   @Override
   public boolean isOpen() {
      return true;
   }
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//inlineFileObjectCreated  -- you can create a StringBuilder Object for a example

```
ByteArrayDataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource("file name", "contentType", inlineFileObjectCreated.getBytes() );

                JavaMailSender mailSender = (JavaMailSender) ServicesHome.getService("javaMailSender");
                MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
                MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
                mimeMessageHelper.setTo(toArray);           
                mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("");
                mimeMessageHelper.setText("");
                mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment("filename", source);
                mailSender.send(mimeMessageHelper.getMimeMessage());
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import javax.activation.DataSource;

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        byte[] bytes;
        String contentType;
        String name;

        public ByteArrayDataSource( String name, String contentType, byte[] bytes ) {
          this.name = name;
          this.bytes = bytes;
          this.contentType = contentType;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
          return contentType;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() {
          return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        }

        public String getName() {
          return name;
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
          throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
      }
```