# "Passed-in resource contains an open stream" when trying to email an attachment using Spring's MailSender

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an attachment using JavaMail via Spring 3's MailSender, but I keep getting this error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailPreparationException: Could not prepare mail; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Passed-in Resource contains an open stream: invalid argument. JavaMail requires an InputStreamSource that creates a fresh stream for every call.
```

I've found and followed others' advice on this (e.g., [how to use spring send email with attachment use InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677490/how-to-use-spring-send-email-with-attachment-use-inputstream)), but can't figure out why my `InputStream` would be open. I've tried a couple of different variations to create the `InputStreamSource` for the attachment (which is a `String`) and had the same problem with both approaches.

approach 1:

```
message.addAttachment(
    filenameBase + "_" + DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()) + ".csv",
        new InputStreamSource() {
            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                            return IOUtils.toInputStream(content);
            }
        });
```

approach 2:

```
message.addAttachment(
    filenameBase + "_" + DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()) + ".csv",
        new ByteArrayResource(content.getBytes()));
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `InputStreamSource` and not the `InputStreamResource` class? The message is only thrown for `InputStreamSource` implementations that are also `Resource` implementations. I assumed you use the `MimeMessageHelper` to construct the `MimeMessage` to send.

Comment: `ByteArrayResource` is both an `InputStreamSource` and a `Resource`, though I've seen quite a few examples where people used it in this case. In the first example it's definitely an `InputStreamSource` since I'm creating the class directly, but I still see the error. I do use `MimeMessageHelper` to construct the `MimeMessage`.

Comment: If you see the error you aren't using the classes you are expecting to use. Check the code of the `MimeMessageHelper` and you will see that this message will only be thrown for an `InputStreamSource` that is also a `Resource` so it simply cannot be thrown in the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it looks like this wasn't the problem - there was another attachment call that wasn't using InputStreamSource correctly (which seems a bit weird as the line numbers were lining up with this one)...